# Load full Website WinRT

Tags: windows-runtime, httpclient

i want to load the Kepler reference Page with HttpClient like this:

```
string resourceAddress = _url;
            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, resourceAddress);
            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
            // Do not buffer the response:
            HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
            response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request,
                 HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead);



            using (Stream responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
            {
                int read = 0;
                byte[] responseBytes = new byte[(Int32)responseStream.Length];
                do
                {
                    read = await responseStream.ReadAsync(responseBytes, 0, responseBytes.Length);
                } while (read != 0);
            }
```

But i think, the Page won´t be loaded complete, like without all images and iframes etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downloading just the first piece of html is rarely going to be enough to give you all the elements of the page, even if you parse it and include all the linked images etc. There is also css and javascript that will bring new content into view when you open a page in a browser and getting all this yourself is going to be an effort similar to implementing your own browser. Your best bet would be to either just load the page once in a WebView control and let it cache its content or use a WebView and scan the DOM to try to get all the elements. You could also write a web service that would download the page for you and just deliver you the whole package... assuming that the page doesn't require authentication.

Comment: thats not really what i want! I want to measure the time a website takes to load! I don´t want to use a webview or sth like that! Load it into a stream and measure the it takes is just enough! But yee, it works but only the first time, if i start it another time it takes much less time, because i think it uses a cache or something! But i don´t know how to stop caching....

Comment: Well, the only sensible thing to do to download the full page is to use WebView, which doesn't seem to have an option to disable caching (or rather - I have not seen one). Using HttpWebRequest you could avoid caching easily, but you could not realistically download entire page for any arbitrary page. If you control the page you are loading - you could configure it to request the browser not to cache it. Lastly - perhaps WebView.InvokeScript could allow you to issue some request that would prevent caching, but I don't know JavaScript enough to help you there.